# How to set custom primary color for dark mode in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a dark theme application in which dark color is `#262626`. I have set the `palette` mode to dark and also set primary main value to above hex dark color, but still it's not showing me default material UI dark theme color.

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode:'dark',
    primary: {
      main: "#262626",
      light: "#FFFFFF",
      dark: "#000000",
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#323232"
    },
  }
});
```

What wrong am I doing here? I guess I am setting the wrong values for the `light` and `dark` properties. Does anyone know what the actual problem is?

I am using Material UI `5.10.16`.

Answer (score 1):

According to MUI [document](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/dark-mode/):

> To use custom palettes for light and dark modes, you can create a function that will return the correct palette depending on the selected mode.

Here is a very basic example that starts with a custom `dark` color palette and toggle modes on click. But for a full guide on this, including use of context to share the toggle and enable system preference, check the MUI [document](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/dark-mode/#dark-mode-with-a-custom-palette) on the subject.

Example: (live demo on: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yukrxr?file=src/App.js))

```
import React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { pink, teal, grey } from '@mui/material/colors';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const getDesignTokens = (mode) => ({
  palette: {
    mode,
    ...(mode === 'light'
      ? {
          //  palette values for light mode
          primary: { main: pink[100] },
          text: {
            primary: grey[900],
          },
        }
      : {
          //  palette values for dark mode
          primary: { main: teal[700] },
          text: {
            primary: '#fff',
          },
        }),
  },
});

export default function App() {
  const [mode, setMode] = React.useState('dark');
  const toggleColorMode = () => {
    setMode((prevMode) => (prevMode === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'));
  };

  const theme = React.useMemo(() => createTheme(getDesignTokens(mode)), [mode]);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Box
        sx={{
          display: 'flex',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          bgcolor: 'primary.main',
          color: 'text.primary',
          borderRadius: 1,
          p: 3,
          cursor: 'pointer',
        }}
        onClick={toggleColorMode}
      >
        {`Click to change to ${mode === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark'}`}
      </Box>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Hope that this could help as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

To set a custom primary color for dark mode in Material-UI, you can use the `MuiThemeProvider` component to create a custom theme and override the default `palette.primary` color. Here is a very simple example for reference

```
import React from 'react'
import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: 'dark', // Set the theme to dark mode
    primary: {
      main: '#e91e63' // Set the primary color to pink
    }
  }
})

function App() {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      {/* Add your Material-UI components here */}
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I think you are using older version of material UI. I am facing this issue on Material UI 5.10.16

Comment: The signature '(options?: ThemeOptions | undefined, ...args: object[]): Theme' of 'createMuiTheme' is deprecated. Use import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles' instead.